PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 6): Colorful Gifts
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
It’s Christmas, and your family has gathered from all over Europe to celebrate at your Uncle Thomas’s house in France.
When it’s time to hand out presents, you notice that almost none of them are wrapped in normally colored paper. Of course, there are a few of the usual reds and greens, but most of the other presents are wrong. There’s a few purples, a lot of pinks, and a ridiculous number of oranges and blues.
It’s your job to hand out presents. First, your Tia Juana hands you hers: two boxes wrapped in blue. Then you see one from Uncle Thomas. It’s pink. Aunt Emily, who is British, has no fewer than six oranges. Tia Juana’s brother, Tio Santiago, seems to be a little saner, with five green presents. And then your Uncle Otto, from Germany, hands you eight dark blues. You’re beginning to wonder how they all found the time to wrap these, in between other preparations and the hours long plane rides to get here.
The adults are finished, but there are still a lot of presents under the tree. Your cousin Hilla, from Finland, has wrapped eight pink presents, and cousin Jakub, from the Czech Republic, has three yellows. Mikolaj, one of the Polish cousins, has three green presents. Tia Juana’s son, José, also has a green. Mikolaj’s sister, Celina, hands you a purple, just before Uncle Thomas’s daughter hands you a stack of four reds. Mikolaj and Celina’s older sister Aldona has wrapped the most presents; she has nine orange ones, and five dark blues. Just when you think you’ve finished, Celina passes you another purple. And that is, finally, the last present.
Last step:

Along with the presents are a few cards from Aunt Emily. There’s a red one, an orange one, six violet ones, and five more normal ones.


Omg I literally have a very similar theme for my puzzle that I am about to release in a few hours for this calendar!!

@PDT That’s funny! Great minds think alike, I guess ;)

@Stiv, whoops, I totally forgot to add the year.

The trick is to

 translate the color into the giver's language and index into it by the number of gifts.

The adults:

 Tia Juana, Spanish, 2 blue: azul
 Uncle Thomas, French, 1 pink: rose
 Aunt Emily, English, 6 oranges: oranges
 Tio Santiago, Spanish, 5 green: verde
 Uncle Otto, German, 8 dark blues: dunkelblau

The kids:

 cousin Hilla, Finnish, 8 pink: vaaleanpunainen
 cousin Jakub, Czech, 3 yellows: žlutý
 cousin Mikolaj, Polish, 3 green: zielony
 primo José, Spanish, 1 green: verde
 cousin Celina, Polish, 1 purple: fiolet
 Uncle Thomas’s daughter, French, 4 reds: rouge
 cousin Aldona, Polish, 9 orange: pomarańcza
 cousin Aldona, Polish, 5 dark blues: ciemnoniebieski
 cousin Celina, Polish, 1 purple: fiolet

This gives us

 an incomprehensible string:
zreel puevfgznf

The last step:

 All from Aunt Emily (English).
 1 red: red
 1 orange: orange
 6 violet: violet

So we

 use rot13 and get
MERRY CHRISTMAS


Yup, this is it! I’ll award the bounty as soon as the site lets me. :)
